# Dynamic linq query for date comparison asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dynamicquery

I have a simplified version of dynamic main query as follows :

```
var items = context.itemsGalore.Where(where).ToList();
```

The where for the Where condition is built dynamically as below.

```
if(compare == "Greater")
{
    where = String.Format("{0} > {1}", DueDate, DateTime.ParseExact(dtValue.ToShortDateString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));                            
}
else if(compare == "Lesser")
{
    where = String.Format("{0} < {1}", field, DateTime.ParseExact(dtValue.ToShortDateString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

However I am getting the following error :
Operator '<' incompatible with operand types 'DateTime' and 'Int32'

How do I go about fixing the issue?

Comment: Why not use lambda expressions? `Where(item => item.DueDate > dtValue)` ?

Comment: LINQ doesn't work with strings. Use lambda expressions instead. And *don't* use `DateTime.ParseExact(dtValue.ToShortDateString()`. Just pass the DateTime value as a parameter. DateTime is a binary type, it has no format. Using strings instead of dates is a *major* bug, especially when you use an *ambiguous* localized pattern. No-one can say what `11/09/2021` means - September 11 or November 9? Even if you use SQL queries, use parameterized queries instead of constructing queries by string concatenation, and pass strongly typed values

Comment: In case you think this is extreme, string concatenation can result in SQL injection ([Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)) or serious real-life problems by mixing up the actual dates, [as this unfortunate family found out](https://english.elpais.com/spanish_news/2020-09-08/the-spanish-family-wrongly-accused-of-child-pornography-due-to-a-mistake-reading-a-date.html). Plus, it's *easier* and faster to use parameterized queries

Comment: Another issue - `DateTime.ParseExact` uses *the current thread's locale* instead of the InvariantCulture. Unless the application runs in a US locale, this code will *switch* the month and day. The resulting query will compare a field with whatever expression that formatting produces. if it produces `04/07/2021` it will compare the field with the result of an integer division. If it produces `2011-04-07` it's the result of subtraction. In countries where the date separator is `.` this will throw a syntax error (Germany, Russia)

Comment: Finally, there's no way EF Core or SQL Server would generate the error `Operator '<' incompatible with operand types 'DateTime' and 'Int32'`. You're using some other library to parse this string into LINQ. What library are you using?

Comment: @Chetan The 'where' is only part of the condition. There are other conditions which will concatenate to the date condition and all of them are working fine. I have simplified the query to ensure the problem is accurately represented.

Answer (score 0):

in the code this section:

```
else if(compare == "Lesser")
{
    where = String.Format("{0} < {1}", field, DateTime.ParseExact(dtValue.ToShortDateString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

The Error is because of the data type of variable 'field' that is not DateTime.

for example run this code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var compare = "Lesser";
        var where = "";
        var DueDate = DateTime.Now;
        var dtValue = DateTime.Now;
        var field = 1;
        if(compare == "Greater")
        {
            where = String.Format("{0} > {1}", DueDate, DateTime.ParseExact(dtValue.ToShortDateString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));                            
        }
        else if(compare == "Lesser")
        {
            where = String.Format("{0} < {1}", field, DateTime.ParseExact(dtValue.ToShortDateString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(where);
    }
}
```

the output is something like this: "1 < 10/07/2021 00:00:00"
and you can not use this as a where clause.

Comment: This is wrong. In fact, the error is caused because the field *is* a `DateTime` but the parameter isn't.  `SomeDate < 11/09/2011` compares the field `SomeDate` with the result of the integer division `11/09/2011`. You can't compare different types in *any* language unless there's a way to convert to a common type. In fact, if this was a valid SQL condition the types would be *the same*.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's ok but not in the where clause! 
I add some sample code in my answer.

Comment: Remove the sentence about dynamic languages because it's not relevant. The problem is that the code results in an invalid SQL condition

Comment: @MiladDastanZand The comment "The Error is because of the data type of variable 'field' that is not DateTime." is not correct. That field is a datetime field present in the table. AS Panagiotis is explaining, the issue is the 10/07/2021 00:00:00 part of the example that you have given.